# How to use chmod -R in pipeline in shell

Tags: shell, unix, chmod

I am writing a shell script where I need to change permissions to the extracted set of files and folders from a double zipped tarball.

My code line is:

```
gzip -dc <file.tar.gz> | tar -tvzf - | cut -d"/" -f3 | uniq | xargs chmod -R 755
```

but the tarball extract is in the other folder. How can I append the path to the extracted folder from `uniq` and change the permission?

Comment: What is the meaning of the sentence _the tarball extract is in the other folder_? Why don't you provide the folder name explicitly to the `chmod` command, or do a `cd` to that folder before running the pipeline? Perhaps it would help if you would add to your question an example line coming out from `uniq`, and how the `chmod` command should look like.

Comment: cd is not in my requirement. You can underrate my question its okay. Anyways I have solved this query myself and without the use of cd or some traditional methods that you are trying to suggest.

Comment: If you now have a solution which suits you, why not posting it as an answer? It is perfectly legal in SO to answer your own question, since others with a similar problem could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet :

```
perm_name=$(gzip -dc ${RELEASE_DIR}/${REL_PACKAGE}|tar -tvzf - |cut -d"/" -f3|sort|uniq)
arr=(${perm_name})

for i in ${arr[@]}
do 
f=${arr[t]}

find ${INSTALL_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -name ${f} -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
t=$(($t+1))
done;
```